# How to make toString to check 2 variables

Tags: javascript, html

I must check if my input has "/0" to prevent div to zero. How can I correctly check it? Does `toString` needs here?

```
function div(input) {
    var input = document.getElementById("t");
    var lastElement = (input.value.length - 1);

    //alert(input.value[lastElement-1]);
    //alert(input.value[lastElement]);


    if((input.value[lastElement - 1].toString) === "/") {
        if((input.value[lastElement].toString) === "0") {
            alert(" / to Zero");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if ( document.getElementById("t").value.slice(-2) === '/0' ) {...`

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to use regex.

```
function div(input) 
{
    var inputValue = document.getElementById("t").value;

    if (inputValue.match(new RegExp('/0$')))
    { 
        alert(" / to Zero");
    }
}
```